# How to get timestamp format of a string date/time and return same format after some change in Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a lot of variables of dates and times and I need to setTimezone in an abstract file. So I don't know anything about what is my times or dates format.

How I can keep the same format after changing the timezone? Or is there any way to find what is my date and time format?

For example, I have a timestamp like `Y-m-d H:i` and in my abstract class I'm changing the time zone by `Carbon::parse($timestamp)->setTimezone($userTimezone)` but with this line of code I'm losing my timestamp format and this code should convert multi-format of date and times. Another timestamp may have a format like `Y/m/d H:I:s`

I need something like this:
`$format = Carbon::parse($timestamp)->getFormat(); // Returns 'Y-m-d H:i'`

Or this can help; How I can setTimezone of a string timestamp without changing the format? `date_default_timezone_get` and `date_default_timezone_set` is not a good idea for this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no information about the date format and at the same time want to operate on those dates and keep the original format, this is more difficult because you have to somehow recognize the date format before operating on it.  Without information about the date format, this cannot be clearly determined because there are many different ways to write the date.

If you don't know the date format and can't determine it, one approach might be to try parsing the date using different formats and see which one is correct.  You can do this in a loop, using different formats and checking whether the parsing was successful.  However, this is quite a complex and uncertain approach.

```
$possibleFormats = ['Y-m-d H:i:s', 'd F Y', 'other_format', 'etc'];

$matchedFormat = '';
foreach ($possibleFormats as $format) {
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $data);
    if ($date instanceof Carbon) {
        // Date parsed correctly in the given format
        $matchedFormat = $format;
        break;
    }
}

// #Do something with $date
return $date->format($matchedFormat);
```

This is problematic if you don't know all the possible formats that may occur and whether this may change in the future.  If this is the case, this method will not get you 100% correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but the parse method attempts to figure out if the variable passed in is in fact a date of some type. It will run it through various functions. Read the source code!

The timezone is dependent on your application, for example Laravel has it set somewhere else and will default to that setting. BUT if needed the example provides it. It is to normalize the date

Lastly the format method returns a string representation of a date instead of an object you have to dive into to figure stuff out.

Basicly the parse is to try and set some data as a actual date and sets it as a Carbon instance (object). If it can't it will throw an error. You can then "check" by putting the parse in a try catch. To actually inspect what the date is, say maybe your looking for a birthdate, common sense should dictate a user can't be under 18 and probably not over a 100. So you can then validate the response for the most part.

Timezone you can't get from a user unless you attempt by IP address and location. This is wholly inaccurate so if possible you need the user to define what timezone they are trying to use.

Answer (score -1):

You can simple change to:

```
Carbon::parse($timestamp)->setTimezone($userTimezone)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Comment: If you read the question, I don't have a format and I don't know anything about that, it can be anything. `Y-m-d H:i` or even `d F Y`.

Comment: So isn't it enough to pass a variable to the ->format($format) function?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but exactly I do not have the format. and I need it.